# WPF layout and specific "data-binding"

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm writing a WPF 95% GUI application, and need a specific shortcut-icon behaviour.
One image is sometimes better than (lots of) words, so here's the basic layout:
(as a new user, couldn't attach an image...)

http://imageshack.us/f/705/appb.jpg/

-Every icons in the bottom sub menu represents a control "page" in the app - FIXED icons.
-The icons on the left are shortcuts - recent and favourites - according to clicks on the bottom icons.
-I'm using stack-panels as containers, and the number of items is fixed.
-every control set has it's own context-menu.

What I'm trying to accomplish is as follows:
When the user clicks an item in the bottom menu, I want it to "magically appear" in the "Recent" panel. When user clicks "remove" (context menu) at the "Recent" panel, I need the (right-clicked) icon to go away.

Right now my (working) solution is unbelievably cumbersome, and I'm sure an elegant one exists..

Would very much appreciate any advice,
Daniel.

Comment: I assume I need some sort of data-binding, maybe not in the exact meaning of it in C#, because I want the fav and recent objects to act almost the same as the menu-icons themselves, meaning opening the correct window, showing tooltips, etc.
what I'm doing now, is dynamically populating the stack-panels on various events with copies of the "real" objects. I must admit - it's nasty...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern for this? If not, you should be.

So, assuming you're using MVVM, would something like this work for you:

```
class BottomPanelViewModel
{
    public BottomPanelViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<PageViewModel>();
        ItemsView = new ListCollectionView(Items);
        ItemsView.CurrentChanged += SelectionChanged;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PageViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
    public ListCollectionView ItemsView { get; private set; }

}    

class RecentPanelViewModel
{
    public RecentPanelViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<PageViewModel>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PageViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
}

class WindowViewModel
{
    public WindowViewModel()
    {
        BottomPanel = new BottomPanelViewModel();
        RecentPanel = new RecentPanelViewModel();

        BottomPanel.CurrentChanged +=  (s, e) =>
        {
            RecentPanel.Items.Add(BottomPanel.ItemsView.CurrentItem);
        };
    }

    public BottomPanelViewModel BottomPanel { get; private set; }
    public RecentPanelViewModel RecentPanel { get; private set; }
}
```

In your window constructor, create a WindowViewModel instance and use it as your DataContext:

```
public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new WindowViewModel();
}
```

Then in your XAML you can bind to the properties of the WindowViewModel:

```
<Window ...>
    <DockPanel>
        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding BottomPanel.ItemsView}"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding RecentPanel.Items}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Explanation: the WindowViewModel contains a BottomPanelViewModel and a RecentPanelViewModel. Each contain an ObservableCollection of Items, and the bottom panel also exposes a collection view. The collection view allows us to track the current selection in the UI.

I'm using simple ListBoxes in the example XAML, but you can use whatever ItemsControl you like.

When the selection changes in the bottom panel, the window view model hears this and adds the selected item to the recent panel's ObservableCollection. You'll obviously want to add logic here to check for duplicates etc.

Comment: not using MVVM - pretty new to C# and WPF :(
thanks, will try to understand after reading some MVVM tutorial

Comment: @BoJl4apa: Yes, it's a shame that most WPF tutorials don't start with MVVM. If you use it from the very beginning you'll find things a *lot* easier.